# Выбор нескольких пунктов как вконтакте помогите найти решение!

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Нужно вот такое реализовать, может быть кто сталкивался или знает где лежит решение?

[image]

Comment: `<offtop>` Warning: БизнесМолодость == МММ == лохотрон `</offtop>`

Примерно похожий плагин: [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот jQuery плагин подойдёт:  [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: а как с него ловить данные? ну вот установил работает, но данные почему-то не ловит в форму.

Comment: Так же, как и из обычного `<select>`. Например, jQuery [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val)

[Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/d8w04xaa/)